# I am using pdf_viewer_plugin and in Android Studio I have no problem, but when I build APK and try to view the PDF from the APP, the APP crashes?

Tags: android, flutter, pdf

So I am using Android Studio and Flutter to build an APP in which there is a PDF and I am using `pdf_viewer_plugin: ^1.0.0+2` to preview the PDF inside the APP. When I connect my phone using cable and run the APP I have no issues what so ever to open the screen and view the PDF, but when I click on Build->APK and install the APK from the file created and go to the same screen with the PDF viewer the whole APP crashes. I can see the screen opens and even the loading indicator I have put it is spinning, but when it suppose to open the PDF it simply crash the whole APP. Can someone help me?

This is my flutter docktor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Linux, locale bg_BG.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at /home/dimitar/flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (преди 4 седмици), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /home/dimitar/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /usr/local/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Mi A2 • 2928015 • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is some of the code I am using:

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

  return directory.path;
}

Future<File> get _localFile async {
  final path = await _localPath;
  return File('$path/teste.pdf');
}

Future<File> writeCounter(Uint8List stream) async {
  final file = await _localFile;

  // Write the file
  return file.writeAsBytes(stream);
}

Future<bool> existsFile() async {
  final file = await _localFile;
  return file.exists();
}

Future<Uint8List> fetchPost() async {
  final response =
      await http.get('https://expoforest.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/exemplo.pdf');
  final responseJson = response.bodyBytes;

  return responseJson;
}

void loadPdf() async {
  await writeCounter(await fetchPost());
  await existsFile();
  path = (await _localFile).path;

  if (!mounted) {
    return;
  } else {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

UPDATE: My main question is how can I debug the APK file that I created to find what is going on?

Comment: Proguard may be blocking the pdf plugin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a file called proguard-rules.pro in your **android/app** directory.

Add this line of code to it:

```
 -keep class com.shockwave.** { *; }
```

Now in your app level build.gradle file, add this to your buildType:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

So that your buildType folder looks something like this:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```

Then run flutter build apk --**buildTypeName**

Example:

```
flutter build apk --release
```

EXPLANATION: Proguard is probably blocking your app from using the pdf viewer library. That's probably why your app runs in debug mode, but not after building the apk.

According to the [plugin source code](https://github.com/lubritto/Pdf_Viewer_Plugin/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/example/pdfviewerplugin/PdfViewerPlugin.java) here, the package name is com.example.pdfviewerplugin, which is why I added com.example to the proguard code.

Try it, and see if it works.

Comment: What buildType are you using?

Comment: release, as you have suggested

Comment: `W/Gralloc3(12469): allocator 3.x is not supported
D/com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore(12469): Starting PdfiumAndroid 1.9.0
W/lease.myreleas(12469): Accessing hidden field Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->descriptor:I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/jniPdfium(12469): Init FPDF library` 
is this information helpful by any means?

Comment: Probably. add -keep class com.shockwave.** { *; } to your proguard

Comment: so add a second line?

Comment: it worked! Thank you very much! I have to idea how to know that if you havent talk me. I am new to flutter.

Comment: Funny enough, I'm new to flutter too. I just learned about proguard yesterday :)

Comment: Good timing. I wanted to ask you where do you learn flutter from? What is your source?

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212868/discussion-between-wilson-o-wilson-and-dimitar).

Comment: best answer ..thanks man